# Checking datetime in inside the list of datetime in C# linq lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of my datetime

```
 List<DateTime> myDateTimeList = new List<DateTime>();
```

I want to get all database records where the datetime is contained in myDateTimeList.
Below is how I've tried to get those records.

**Method1**

```
var result = myEntity.Where(x => myDateTimeList.Any(dt => dt == x.CreationDateTime));
```

**Method2**

```
var result = myEntity.Where(x => myDateTimeList.Contains(x.CreationDateTime));
```

Both methods throw the exception

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string.

The exception throw when calling

```
await result.ToListAsync();
```

How can I fix this?

**Edit:** Datatype of myEntity.CreationDateTime is DateTime with **NOT NULLABLE**.

Comment: what's the type of `myEntity.CreationDateTime` ?

Comment: What if you try calling `myEntity.ToList()`, does error persist?

Comment: check both the type of `myEntity.CreationDateTIme` and `myDateTimeList`. One of them is not an Actual `DateTime` but a character string

Comment: Change the column to an actual date type. The error complains that the column is a string, not a date. That's a critical bug - you have on idea what is stored in that column. Perhaps it's `potato`, perhaps it's `4/7/2023` which is ... what? July 4th or April 7th? You can only assume and guess. A *lot* of ugly bugs have been caused by such assumptions

Comment: Change the table column to an appropriate date type, eg `date` if it only contains a date, `datetime2` with a valid precision if it includes a time component. Change your model's `CreationDateTime` to `DateTime`. This will avoid all conversion and sorting errors and allow SQL Server to use date optimizations in queries and indexes

Comment: @Roe myDateTimeList and myEntity.CreationDateTime both should be DateTime format, or else it shows compile time error. I guess there is some error/format mismatch in the data which he holds in those objects.

Comment: `DateTime` is a type, not a format. In the database `date`, `datetime`, `datetime2`, `time`, `datetimeoffset` have no format, they're binary values. It's the same for the .NET Types, `DateTime`, `DateTimeOffset`, `DateOnly`, `TimeOnly`. There shouldn't be any strings involved

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I already edited my question, Datatype of myEntity.CreationDateTime is DateTime with NOT NULLABLE.

Comment: @GuruStron, I already edit my question, yes, the exception throws when calling await result.ToListAsync();

Comment: @StevenSann _"myEntity.CreationDateTime is DateTime with NOT NULLABLE."_ - should not be a reason for this exception but is the data column nullable in database?

Comment: @GuruStron, it is not nullable in the database schema also.

Comment: @StevenSann what is the datatype in the database?

Comment: @GuruStron,`[CreationDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL`

Comment: That's very strange. Without [mre] it would be hard to tell anything.

Comment: Post the actual *full* exception text, including the stack trace. The error may come from a different call. Or you may have a type converter that throws. Or `CreationDateTime` may be calculated, trying to change the "format" of the property by serializing and parsing the actual date.

Comment: Are you using recent EF Core? I believe you are running [into a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27464) with the conversion of constants to SQL when using columns of type `datetime` which is considered obsolete instead of `datetime2` (!).  You can add `HaveColumnType("datetime")` to your definition of the column.

Comment: @NetMage, yes, I'm using EF Core.